# Running a python cgi script on own webserver

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I'm trying to run this simple file ([from this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm))

/var/www/cgi-bin/textarea.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
if form.getvalue('textcontent'):
   text_content = form.getvalue('textcontent')
else:
   text_content = "Not entered"

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>";
print "<title>Text Area - Fifth CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2> Entered Text Content is %s</h2>" % text_content
print "</body>"
```

/var/www/index.html:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/textarea.py" method="post" target="_blank">
<textarea name="textcontent" cols="40" rows="4">
Type your text here...
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

On `localhost` I can see the textarea but after hitting the submit button, firefox wants me to download the .py file.

I have added a few lines into my config file:

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf :

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options ExecCGI
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
Options All
</Directory>
```

I hope that this is the correct config file, since I don't have a httpd.conf
What am I missing?

Comment: If you're running your own web server, and learning this from scratch, why are you using old-style CGI instead of WSGI (or a simple framework)? Do you need your code to be portable to the 1990s?

Comment: No I don't and thanks for the tip with WSGI. But still I'd like to have an answer, if this is so simple.